# Does the P(D | +a) in the context of bayesian network mean that we have to compute both P(+d |+a) and P(-d|+a)?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, inference, bayesian-network

[image]

I've been asked to calculate P(D|+a) using inference by enumeration.

My attempt resulted in :

$P(D|+a) \:\propto{D}\:P(D,+a)\\ =\sum_{b,c} P(D,+a,b,c)\\
=\sum_{b,c} P(D|c) P(c|+a,b) P(+a)P(b|+a)\\
=P(D|-c) P(-c|+a,-b) P(+a)P(-b|+a)+P(D|+c) P(c|+a,-b) P(+a)P(-b|+a)+P(D|-c) P(c|+a,+b) P(+a)P(+b|+a)+P(D|+c) P(c|+a,+b) P(+a)P(+b|+a)$

and then calculate for each +d and -d by plugging in the values of the tables.

I've watched cs188's lecture on bayesian nets and they said: "Capital B is still a variable, we're computing a table where B is a variable. That means that we effectively will compute this twice. We'll let B equal plus, compute this quantity. We'll let B equal negative B, compute the quantity and that will give us two entries in the table and then we'll sum those together that gives our renormalization factor and we get the conditional after we normalize it".

However, when I asked my lecturer about the assignment on whether we should calculate both P(+d,+a) and P(-d,+a) they said that I should make a full joint distribution table first? I mean, the table for the necessary data are all already there?

Answer (score 1):

A better notation is $\mathbb P(D|A=+a)$ to see the distinction between a RV and a specific value. Then, $D$ is a RV, not a specific value so, yes, it should be calculated for both $d$ and $-d$. In the end, a table with two rows will be produced. You don't have to make a full joint distribution in order to answer $\mathbb P(D|A=+a)$.